# How to implement the head function using fst function

Tags: haskell

I admit this is my homework. But I really couldn't find a good solution after working hard on it.

There might be some stupid ways to accomplish this, like:

```
myHead (x:[]) = x
myHead (x:y:xs) = fst (x, y)
```

But I don't think that's what the teacher wants.

BTW, error-handling is not required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something stupid like that has to be what your teacher means. There are plenty ways to write the same thing, and yours is as good as any.

Comment: @kqr is right.  Any attempt to implement it with fst is going to look stupid, since you really have to use pattern matching to do it and why wouldn't you use pattern matching to simply match and return the first element?  Although you can replace your two lines with one: `myHead (x:xs) = fst (x, xs)`.

Comment: Given `(.:) = (.).(.)` it could also be written as `myHead = foldr1 $ fst .: (,)`. (Although `fst .: (,) = const`, so again, stupid.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very natural function that's not in the prelude called "uncons" which is the inverse of uncurried cons.

```
cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
uncurry cons :: (a, [a]) -> [a]

uncons :: [a] -> (a, [a])
uncons (x:xs) = (x, xs)
```

You can use it to implement head as

```
head = fst . uncons
```

---

Why is `uncons` natural?

You can think of a list as the datatype that's defined through the use of two constructor functions

```
nil :: [a]
nil = []

cons :: (a, [a]) -> [a]
cons (a,as) = a:as
```

You can also think of it as the data type which is deconstructed by a function

```
destruct :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
destruct [] = Nothing
destruct (a:as) = Just (a, as)
```

It's well beyond this answer to explain why those are so definitively tied to the list type, but one way to look at it is to try to define

```
nil      :: f a
cons     :: (a, f a) -> f a
```

or

```
destruct :: f a -> Maybe (a, f a)
```

for any other container type `f`. You'll find that they all have very close relationships with lists.

You can almost already see `uncons` in the second case of the definition of `destruct`, but there's a `Just` in the way. This is `uncons` is better paired with `head` and `tail` which are not defined on empty lists

```
head [] = error "Prelude.head"
```

so we can adjust the previous answer to work for *infinite streams*. Here we can think of infinite streams as being constructed by one function

```
data Stream a = Next a (Stream a)

cons :: (a, Stream a) -> Stream a
cons (a, as) = Next a as
```

and destructed by one function

```
uncons :: Stream a -> (a, Stream a)
uncons (Next a as) = (a, as)

-- a. k. a.
uncons stream = (head stream, tail stream)
```

the two being inverses of one another.

Now we can get `head` for `Stream`s by getting the first element of the return tuple from `uncons`

```
head = fst . uncons
```

And that's what `head` models in the `Prelude`, so we can pretend like lists are infinite streams and define head in that way

```
uncons :: [a] -> (a, [a])
uncons (a:as) = (a, as)

-- a. k. a.
uncons list = (head list, tail list)

head = fst . uncons
```

Comment: I searched on google for a while, but couldn't find much information on the 'uncons' function. Could you please give a bit more info about it, as I'm still a Haskell newbie. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add some notes to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're expected write to your own cons List type, then it *might* make more sense. Although type synonyms can't be recursive, so you end up using a non-tuple data constructor, making the tuple superfluous.. it would look like:

```
data List a = Nil | List (a, List a)
        deriving( Show )

head :: List a -> a
head (List c) = fst c
```

Answer (score 1):

Like already said in the comments, this is just a silly task and you won't get something you could call a good implementation of `head`.

Your solution, for those requirements, is just fine – as the only change I would replace `(x:y:xs)` with `(x:y:_)` since `xs` isn't used at all (which would actually cause a compiler warning in some settings). In fact, you could do that with `y` as well:

```
myHead (x:_:_) = fst (x, undefined)
```

There would be alternatives that look perhaps not *quite* so [useless use of `fst`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_use_of_cat#Useless_use_of_cat), i.e. don't just build a tuple by hand and immediately deconstruct it again:

```
myHead' [x] = x
myHead' xs = myHead' . fst $ splitAt 1 xs

myHead'' = foldr1 $ curry fst

myHead''' = fromJust . find ((==0) . fst) . zip [0..]
```

but you could rightfully say that these are just ridiculous.